# How do I remove or cancel the directional tag from the original css using another css?

Tags: css

```
html, body, forms {
direction: rtl;
}
```

This is what I want to remove from the original code coz in IE7 it my slider is not align when this code is present

Comment: Remove/delete the property from your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

To override it:

```
html, body {
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the prompt reply I already have than this yet still it won't fix my problem. What I really want to do is to remove the said tag in my iefix.css which I created to fix the bug of IE7 browser when rendering my website. Coz as I've tried removing that tag in the developer mode in IE7 everything went well with the alignment. But I can't remove it in the main css since we still need that directional tag on other browsers.

Comment: @user3118232 Overriding it should serve the same purpose.  Notice that I used `ltr` instead of `rtl`.

Comment: Yes I know but what I really need is to remove the entire code in my fix css file